# Python: magic methods that shouldn't be used

Tags: python, coding-style, magic-methods

I've created a class that is a `tuple` wrapper and tuples doesn't support item mutations.
Should I leave `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` implementation or implement those methods like e.g. below (thus fall in kind of Refused Bequest code smell)? Which approach is more pythonic? Aren't custom exceptions better in such case?

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    """
    :raise: Always.
    :raises: TypeError
    """
    self.data_set[key] = value  # Raise from tuple.

def __delitem__(self, key):
    """
    :raise: Always.
    :raises: TypeError
    """
    raise TypeError("Item deletion is unsupported")  # Custom exceptions thrown.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is supposed to be a proper tuple subtype (according to [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)), then it should behave the same way as a tuple wrt/ to set/del - which as Guillaume mentions is the default behaviour if you just define neither `__setitem__` nor `__delitem__`. I don't see how that would fall into the "Refused Bequest" category.

If your class uses a tuple as part of it's implementation but is NOT supposed to be a proper tuple subtype, then do whatever makes sense - but if you don't want to allow item assignment / deletion then again the simplest thing is to not implement them.

Comment: By Refused Bequest I mean that this class claims to implement `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` but it's behaviour shows that it doesn't support those operations.

Comment: AOK. Well actually (as I mentionned) if the goal is to not support item assignment and deletion, then indeed it makes no sense implementing these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Although that is a matter of taste, I think you should not implement them at all. A class that has a `__setitem__, __delitem__` implements the mutable collection *protocol* (either implicitly, or even explicitly by using [collection abstract base classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html)). Your class just does not support this interface, that's it, and the user has neither reason nor right to assume it does

Answer (score 0):

Implement one or the other or both if they make sense for your custom class.

If you implement `__setitem__()` you will be able to use `yourobject[yourindex] = yourvalue` syntax in your code (with the semantic that you choose to implement).

If you implement `__delitem__()` you will be able to use `del yourobject[yourindex]`

It makes no sense to explictly implement a method just to raise an Exception, Python will do it by default:

```
class Test(object):
    pass
test = Test()
test['foo'] = 'bar' # will call Test.__setitem__() which is not explicitly defined
```

will give `TypeError: 'Test' object does not support item assignment`